# perform a get operation for Java set

Tags: java, get, hashset, treeset

Assuming I have a set. I would like to get back a certain element.
I have an element that I created which has its key fields (used by compareTo) but not the other fields. The real element is in the set. The contains method returns true but I want the element itself. This should be done efficiently. How can that be done?

Comment: It can be done by using `Map` instead of `Set`, using the same object for both key and value. Since `Set` internally uses a `Map` anyway, it'll use the same amount of memory.

Comment: Please add a code in your post

Comment: You can encapsulate the key fields you mentioned into an object that can be used as the key in the `Map`

Comment: Set collection serves to check presence of elements, but not to retrieve them, use map instead!
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html